# reCAPTCHA always coming across as true

Tags: php

What is wrong with this bit of code.  Whether I tick the reCAPTCHA or not, it goes onto the else clause.

```
<?php
// This is added for Google Captcha

    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $privatekey = '6LdBjyATAAAAABZe1O-DKBEQnOIzanoVLGEvsvyu';

    $response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $data = json_decode($response);

    if($response.success==false){
        echo "<h2>Spam Spam go away</h2><p>And if you're not spam, we apologise.  Please go back and tick the reCAPTCHA box.</p><p>Thank you</p>";
        die();
    } else {
// do loads of clever stuff
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($response);`  That's the javascript way of getting array/object values; in PHP, the period is for concatenation. If `$response` is an array, it would be `$response['success']`, if it's an object, it's `$response->success`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP the dot `.` operator is for appending strings.
Because the weakly typing of PHP you can append strings to everything.

This line of code:

```
if($response.success==false){
```

Would append 'success' to the $response `stdClass`.
If you enable notices, this would trigger a notice, because of that the string is not inside quotes.

The output string is in that case `success`, and that is `not false` in PHP.

What you want, is this:

```
if($response->success==false){
```

You need to access it as a property of `stdClass`.